# WCF REST service has stopped working and even BasicHttpBinding fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

***UPDATE***
Well, after banging my head against this some more, I finally recreated the service. While I am not sure of the actual root cause at this point, one change I did make was to use the standard System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory instead of the custom one we usually use, now everything works as expected.

I have spent the better part of 2 days trying to figure this out and still am lost so hopefully someone can help me. I have a restful service that also has one soap endpoint that up until this past tuesday ran like a champ. Now, suddenly the wsdl being generated when building in VS 2013 is completely out of whack and none of the end points are working at all. I've gone through everything, reverted back code and config settings to prior to Tuesday (May 10) and still cannot make it work. I've cleared my Temporary ASP Net files, I've reset IIS, blown away code and gotten it fresh, everything I can think of.

Whenever I try to access the service via the REST path I receive the message that no end point was found, when I try via the basic route I get a message indicating an HTTP 415 error. I'm including the sections of my SERVICE config for reference but even this has not changed since Tuesday. We've also tried deploying to other machines and testing on other dev boxes with the same result. I've removed some of the names on purpose. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="FdrBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <security includeTimestamp="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Sha256Rsa15" securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880" proxyAddress="http://10.10.1.54:80" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" useDefaultWebProxy="false"  />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DASBDI_NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DASFDR_NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="TMGTokenService_NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DASSymConnect_NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:59:00" openTimeout="00:59:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AccountViewsSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="AccountViewsSoap1" />
        <binding name="AccountMaintenanceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="AccountMaintenanceSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://openservices.beta.themembersgroup.com/accountviews.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AccountViewsSoap"
      contract="AccountViewsService.AccountViewsSoap" name="AccountViewsSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://openservices.beta.themembersgroup.com/accountmaintenance.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AccountMaintenanceSoap"
      contract="AccountMaintenanceService.AccountMaintenanceSoap"
      name="AccountMaintenanceSoap" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MemberDocuments.ServiceBehavior"
           name="Kinecta.BusinessServices.MemberDocuments.BLSMemberDocuments">
        <endpoint address="BLSMemberDocumentsREST"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
              contract="Kinecta.PublicServiceContracts.IBLSMemberDocuments">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="BLSMemberDocumentsSOAP"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="soapBehavior"
              contract="Kinecta.PublicServiceContracts.IBLSMemberDocuments">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MemberDocuments.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="soapBehavior">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode"
     verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
     System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

[WCF Client before Tuesday May 10 (Endpoints worked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXeLR.png)

[WCF Client After Tuesday May 10 (End Points do not work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kwZn.png)

Comment: Some questions: 1) Did you try to run over HTTP? 2) Is it possible to run the service in VS using IIS express (localhost)? 3) Did you check your SSL certificate? 4) No firewall settings changed?

Comment: We are running over http currently and the service is being run under my local IIS (7.5) rather than IIS express. One thing I've noticed in the WCF test client is that the information and config generated on Tuesday is completely different compared to today.

Comment: I may be 'influenced' by a recent fault of mine, but is it possible the error is not on your end? Somebody that changed something in a database, network, ... ? Worst case, if the code is small-ish, it might be worth a try to paste it all in a new Visual Studio project, maybe?

Comment: Honestly I no one else has touched this code, or any of the pieces but me. And on the service side (ie the service.svc project side) nothing has changed. We use a seperate class/project for all actual business logic and keep the service part bare. I wish I could say someone messed with something but at this point no one has.